# Wordpress on Plesk (Ubuntu) - suddenly white screen with no html returned

Tags: php, wordpress, plesk, plesk-onyx

I can't explain it, I didn't change anything but it seems suddenly today one of my websites on my Plesk environment (Plesk on Ubuntu) is suddenly white. No error, no php errors, nothing (even with `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );` or any other method that would help me find something.

Also the error logs for the domain don't seem to return anything helpful.

As it's Wordpress I tried to rename the plugin folder, theme folder, checked .htaccess, other configs.

But …

I only get a completely empty page when I inspect it.

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

I'm running PHP 7.2.19 with "FPM application served by nginx" but also switching to some other PHP version, updating parameters or switching to apache-serving doesn't do anything.

I also checked other domains on the same Plesk installation, that work all fine.

Any ideas here?

Comment: Could it be due to an auto update that has gone wrong? Do you see the `.maintenance` file on the root folder?

Answer (score 0):

Before you give these solutions a shot I recommend that you restart your server first as the problem might get solved by itself because we know that plesk does a lot of updating in the background.

## Solution 1

Access your error logs `/var/www/vhosts/yoursite.com/logs/access_log` and check if there are 500 errors in there. Meaning that you need to allocate more Memory in the PHP settings of plesk (Plesk > Your Website > PHP Settings) e.g 256 or 512 MB.

Don't forget to add `define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M');` in your **wp-config.php**

## Solution 2

Rename `/plugins/` folder to `/plugins.old/` and create a new empty `plugins` folder then go to /wp-content/ and remove advanced-cache.php. Also in wp-config.php check if you have **define('WP_CACHE', true);** then change it to **false**.

## Solution 3

Your theme could be broken so switch to any default theme to find out.

## Solution 4

Go to Plesk > Your Website > PHP Settings and enable errors. Then add "define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );" into your **wp-config.php**. Try to Visit your administration panel and view random webpages to see the errors as they could give you a clue of what is going on. Then you can google whatever error.

## Solution 4

Go to Plesk > Your Website > Settings > Switch To FastCGI/PHPFPM, Apache/Nginx, etc. Try all of those in combination with different PHP versions.

## Solution 5

Turn off Mod Security from Tools & Settings > Web Application Firewall (ModSecurity)

Comment: Thank you for your help. Nothing of those 5 things did the job.

1.) The access_log is empty!
2.) Even though I have error reporting on and also specified it in the wp-config.php with error_reporting(E_ALL) and other DEBUG options, I do not get anything but a white page.
3.) I renamed plugins and theme, but nothing happens.

Comment: download latest wordpress https://wordpress.org/download/ then extract and replace all the files on your website. Also SSH login to your server and check the group and user permissions using `ls -l` terminal command.